# Turn mod_rewrite on twice?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This code was in my WordPress .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
**RewriteEngine On**
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Since `RewriteEngine On`is already in the .htaccess file do I need to add it again for more redirects since it's in a closing `</IfModule>`? Why is this rewrite code enclosed in the `</IfModule>` anyway? Is it checking for the existance of mod_rewrite???

Comment: You don't need to turn it on twice. And you are right, it's checking whether mod_rewrite is loaded so adding the Rewrites won't cause a 500 Internal Server Error if it's not.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me why I even need to put `RewriteEngine On` in the `.htaccess` file? I'm on shared hosts at Godaddy and I have `.htaccess` files with just this example as the only code: `Redirect 301 /tag/southpaw-throws-left/  http://website.com/softball-tag/southpaw-throws-left/` and the redirect works like the engine is already on.

Comment: Redirect is from mod_alias, not mod_rewrite, that's why you don't need to enable mod_rewrite for those.